# can't login and see frontend after installing an extension

Tags: error, installation

I was installing an extension and it failed. Now the page is not loading and showing following error....   Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.  After deleting maintenance.flag it shows another error.... Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-object in /home/wwwthema/public_html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 600 ... Please give the solution  http://themaorishop.co.nz/

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: yes, cache and sessions i have cleared @Marius

Comment: Temporarily turn on the develper mode and show errors. Edit index.php and uncomment the line `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and change `if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {` to `if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE']) || true) {`. Then you should be able to see where the error originates...hopefully.

Comment: if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE']) || true) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
} 

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    Still showing same error.

Comment: The last think I can recommend is this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/428/146. Follow the steps described in the answer. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your support.. Let me check with my seniors because project is already been live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom Magento theme and are having problems getting extensions to display correctly on the frontend, there is a good chance that it is an issue of file location. Extensions usually install to default/default/ or base/default/ because there is no way for the developer of an extension to predict whether you are using a custom theme or what its name might be.

When using a custom theme, Magento will look in YOUR_CUSTOM_THEME/default/ directory for an extension’s .phtml, .xml, and .css files. If they were installed to the default or base directory, Magento won’t be able to locate them within the theme directory and consequently the extension’s output won’t be displayed.

To display the output of an extension, simply make sure that its files are in the correct locations. Check the base and default directories and see if there are any CSS, XML, or PHTML files for the extension. If so, move the files to the corresponding location within your custom theme.

Finally, refresh your cache and test that the extension’s output is correctly displaying.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes Erin, it was the same problem you have described. The extension installed at wrong place and it was causing error. Now it's working :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was indeed how you corrected the aforementioned error.